# d3.js Lasso Drawing Polygon Shape Search Tool - on a google map (getting the coordinates/users in a given area)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js

[image]

Trying to build a location search app, that displays a google map - on the user drawing on the map it reveals any users that are located within that region.

I've also found this example - but it seems clunky/unsmooth - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/34/

http://jsfiddle.net/4xXQT/156/

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var points = d3.range(1, 5).map(function(i) {
  return [i * width / 5, 50 + Math.random() * (height - 100)];
});

var dragged = null,
    selected = points[0];

var line = d3.svg.line();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("tabindex", 1);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mousedown", mousedown);

svg.append("path")
    .datum(points)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .call(redraw);

d3.select(window)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseup", mouseup)
    .on("keydown", keydown);

d3.select("#interpolate")
    .on("change", change)
  .selectAll("option")
    .data([
      "linear",
      "step-before",
      "step-after",
      "basis",
      "basis-open",
      "basis-closed",
      "cardinal",
      "cardinal-open",
      "cardinal-closed",
      "monotone"
    ])
  .enter().append("option")
    .attr("value", function(d) { return d; })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

svg.node().focus();

function redraw() {
  svg.select("path").attr("d", line);

  var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(points, function(d) { return d; });

  circle.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .on("mousedown", function(d) { selected = dragged = d; redraw(); })
    .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .ease("elastic")
      .attr("r", 6.5);

  circle
      .classed("selected", function(d) { return d === selected; })
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d[0]; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d[1]; });

  circle.exit().remove();

  if (d3.event) {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
  }
}

function change() {
  line.interpolate(this.value);
  redraw();
}

function mousedown() {
  points.push(selected = dragged = d3.mouse(svg.node()));
  redraw();
}

function mousemove() {
  if (!dragged) return;
  var m = d3.mouse(svg.node());
  dragged[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(width, m[0]));
  dragged[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(height, m[1]));
  redraw();
}

function mouseup() {
  if (!dragged) return;
  mousemove();
  dragged = null;
}

function keydown() {
  if (!selected) return;
  switch (d3.event.keyCode) {
    case 8: // backspace
    case 46: { // delete
      var i = points.indexOf(selected);
      points.splice(i, 1);
      selected = points.length ? points[i > 0 ? i - 1 : 0] : null;
      redraw();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've found this example to, but it doesn't appear to work - http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/mymapstoolbar.html

Comment: I've created a basic version of the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/38/ - this allows the user to drag and draw a shape. I need to then conform the shape into  a simpler polygon.

Comment: The latest code - with no bugs - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/40/

Comment: It would be great if the drawn shape could then morph into a more basic polygon shape - resembling the drawn shape. - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3081153

Comment: I've added a clear button and an edit button. The clear button works - but how to a) simplify the shape after the path is completed and b) to edit the shape - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/42/ - I have copied the code in place from this example to see how to reverse engineer the edit spline - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4342190

Comment: Need a shape simplifier - something like this - but its not a geo map though - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5732029

Comment: Another shape simplifier - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6905926

Comment: I've cleaned up the drawing code - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/48/

Comment: I've tried to merge the codes together - so the shape simplifies after creation - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/52/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The latest code "http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/188/"

---

This demonstrates how to draw polygons and freehand shapes.

```
$(".drawfreehand").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("drawfreehand");

    function drawFreeHand(){

        //the polygon
        that.newShape= new google.maps.Polyline({map:that.map,clickable:false});

        //move-listener
        var move = google.maps.event.addListener(that.map,'mousemove',function(e){
            that.newShape.getPath().push(e.latLng);
        });

        //mouseup-listener
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(that.map,'mouseup',function(e){


            google.maps.event.removeListener(move);

            var path= that.newShape.getPath();

            that.newShape.setMap(null);

            that.newShape=new google.maps.Polygon({map:that.map,path:path});


            google.maps.event.clearListeners(that.map.getDiv(), 'mousedown');

            enable()

            that.newShape.setEditable(false);
            that.revealInsidePolygon(that.newShape);

        });
    }

    function disable(){
        that.map.setOptions({
            draggable: false, 
            zoomControl: false, 
            scrollwheel: false, 
            disableDoubleClickZoom: false
        });
    }

    function enable(){
        that.map.setOptions({
            draggable: true, 
            zoomControl: true, 
            scrollwheel: true, 
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true
        });
    }

    disable()

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(that.map.getDiv(),'mousedown',function(e){
        drawFreeHand()
    });


});
```

Comment: The latest code with colour enhancements - http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/180/

Comment: now added the gDouglasPeuker algorithm to simplify the polygon after its drawn http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/188/

Comment: This is quite cool! Is it possible to get the lat/lon of the polygon?

Comment: I am not sure - do you want to have a go at getting this data?

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up the drawing code - and I've placed a function to try and simplify the shape. Having trouble though trying to achieve this though. The path becomes corrupt and becomes empty leaving just a single line.

Here is the code - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/53/

```
 simplifyShape: function(svg){
            console.log("simplifier");

            var area = 1,
                simplify = d3.geo.transform({
                    point: function(x, y, z) {
                        if (z >= area){
                            this.stream.point(x, y);
                        }
                    }
                });

            var path = d3.geo.path()
                .projection(simplify);          

            var shape = d3.select('.selection');
            var coordinates = shape.attr("d");

            area = 1.3;

            shape.attr("d", path)

        }
```

Comment: I've tried to copy down the snowflake sample - but when the mouse goes over it - it disappears - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/54/

Comment: Here is a basic google map script. http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/60/

Comment: Another lasso marker tool - http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-marker-lasso-search-tool.htm

Comment: I've merged the lasso and google map together - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/62/

Comment: Latest code - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/67/

Comment: Latest code with less bugs - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/71/

Comment: This is what I need - but how to implement it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897556/how-do-i-reduce-the-coordinate-count-of-an-arbitrary-svg-path-without-losing-mu

Comment: Integrated the simplifier code - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/77/

Comment: If I could merge all the code on to this as a base - that will be great. http://jsfiddle.net/Vjxpr/25/ - I've tried compiling the basic shape concept onto here - but its not showing up correctly

Comment: This is the example that shows how its possible to create an overlay area and then append d3.js objects to it. But I am unsure how to append the generic drawing shapes to the map and get them to zoom/pan together as one unit - http://jsfiddle.net/Vjxpr/14/

Comment: If only I could use this as a base and merge the drawing code into place - I've started again - this time with just the markers on the map - in an overlay mode - but I am struggling to add the shape to the region - http://jsfiddle.net/Vjxpr/40/

Answer (score 0):

Bringing it all together. A challenge.

- The desired result waiting to happen

[image]
[image]

Ok so I have the drawing and simplifying shape code merged.

I've also found a google map, d3 example - which places down markers in an overlay state on a google map. The markers appear to pan/zoom with the map accordingly.

I would like to bring the drawing shape code into place with the markers - so everything is zoomable/pannable as expected.

Once this is complete then I would like to work on
- editing the shape
- highlighting markers only inside the shape area.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vjxpr/49/

```
shapeSelector = {
        invoke: function(){
            var that = this;

            var width = 500;
            var height = 400;

            // An array to hold the coordinates
            // of the line drawn on each svg.
            var  coords = []
            this.line = d3.svg.line();

            this.drag = this.getDragBehaviours()

            this.svg = d3.select("#canvas1").append("svg")
            .attr({
                width: width,
                height: height
            }).call(that.drag);

            this.bindEvents();            

        }
```

handles the shape drawing features

googleMapHandler.invoke is handling the generate of the google map - and the marker positions/overlay settings.

Comment: I'm able to draw on top of the map - but its not apart of it - if I place the div on the level of the markers. http://jsfiddle.net/Vjxpr/62/ can anyone supervise on this/come across similar problems?

Comment: I've added the editing code from here --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520620/d3-js-edit-existing-shape-path  -- into here for now. http://jsfiddle.net/Vjxpr/75/  - its now possible to draw the shape and edit it, clear it - but I need it to be generated and interactive as part of the map - react if the map is scaled/zoomed/panned.

Comment: Still struggling on this - http://jsfiddle.net/uF9PV/76/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In this example - I've ADDED a dummy shape to the map - similar way to the markers - but I am unsure at this stage - if its possible for the user to draw or edit/engage with the polygon.

I am trying to just move the polygon and rescale it in reference to the map.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/91/

```
var shapelayer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
                .attr("class", "shape");
```

^ add shape layer div

```
        //** shape area **//
        var paths = "M184,174L209,266L345,247L364,143L256,144 L184,174L256,144";

        var shapeArea = shapelayer.append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", "100%") 
        .attr("height", "100%")   
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", paths)
        .each(transformshape)
        .attr("class", "selectioncomplete")


        function transformshape(d) {
            //d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.value.coordinates[1], d.value.coordinates[0]);
            //d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
            return d3.select(this)
            //.style("left", (d.x-25) + "px")
            //.style("top", (d.y-25) + "px");
        }

        //** shape area **//
```

add the shape area with dummy path data.

Comment: I've found this example that doesn't use d3.js at all - http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/95/ - but not familiar with creating polygons in this fashion

Comment: Ok I've got it working with clear/edit polygon shape - http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/102/

Comment: I've added a drawing shape feature - but it won't close when trying to click onto the last node - why is this. http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/106/

Comment: Here is the add polygon code I've found - but still not sure how markers will be highlighted within the region - http://developers.cartodb.com/examples/editing-polygons.html

Comment: Trying to initialize this - http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/110/ -- using this as a base - http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/drawing/drawing-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am now using the general Google map drawing tools for this. As the panning/zooming is handled with the UI.

My outstanding issue now - is to show ONLY the markers in a given shape area. I've started to incorporate code that should hide/show markers - but I need some help to get this working.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/139/

```
    setAllMap: function(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
            this.markers[i].setMap(map);
        }
    },
    clearMarkers: function() {
        this.setAllMap(null);
    },
    showMarkers: function() {
        this.setAllMap(map);
    },
```

Comment: Fixed the code to show/hide ALL markers - http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/147/ - need to figure out - how to hide ALL markers - and SHOW only the ones inside the shape area... need to splice off the array somehow

Comment: Found these examples that could be useful - http://jsfiddle.net/kaiser/wzcst/light/  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522484/google-maps-v3-check-if-point-exists-in-polygon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030127/marker-visibility-in-google-maps  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/5030127/marker-visibility-in-google-maps

Comment: ******* here is the latest demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/168/ - can now edit/add/clear - it highlights the markers only visible in the polygon region. - Would like to clean it up - so the user draws freehand first and then it morphs into a polygon.

Comment: referencing this code to find markers inside a polygon -stackoverflow.com/questions/5030127/marker-visibility-in-google-maps

Comment: Is it possible to use d3.js to create the freehand shape - it then gets converted into a polygon and then gets transcribed into a googlemap shape polygon - or is there a way to create a freehand shape that gets converted into a polygon directly on google maps?

Comment: Here is some freehand example - need to apply it to my example now - http://jsfiddle.net/YsQdh/74/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YsQdh/80/ - latest example of just the freehand drawing

Comment: Improved listener - http://jsfiddle.net/YsQdh/88/

Answer (score 0):

A working example of drawing freehand and converting to a polygon: http://jsfiddle.net/PDf9G/1/

Basically, you do the drawing the way you were already doing it. Keep the canvas div for drawing in back, when the button is clicked, move it to the front. When `dragend` is called convert the array of pixel coordinates you were keeping to lat and lng like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < divCoords.length; i++)
    geoCoords.push(overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(Number(divCoords[i][0]), Number(divCoords[i][1]))));
```

Still needs a lot of cleanup. I was going to continue getting the d3 marker hiding working, but looks like you figured that out.