# d3.js How to simplify a complex path - using a custom algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, d3.js

[image]

I've got a very basic example here. http://jsfiddle.net/jEfsh/57/ that creates a complex path - with lots of points. I've read up on an algorithm that may look over the points and create a simpler set of coordinates. Does anyone have any experience with this - examples on how to loop through the path data and pass it through the algorithm - find the shortest set of points to create a more rudimentary version of the shape?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer-Douglas-Peucker_algorithm

```
var points = "M241,59L237,60L233,60L228,61L224,61L218,63L213,63L209,65L204,66L199,67L196,68L193,69L189,70L187,72L184,72L182,74L179,75L177,76L175,78L173,79L170,81L168,83L165,85L163,87L161,89L159,92L157,95L157,97L155,102L153,105L152,110L151,113L151,117L151,123L150,137L148,180L148,185L148,189L148,193L148,197L148,202L148,206L149,212L151,218L152,222L154,229L154,232L155,235L157,239L158,241L160,245L162,247L163,249L165,251L167,254L169,256L172,258L175,260L178,261L183,265L188,268L193,270L206,273L213,275L220,275L225,275L232,276L238,277L243,277L249,277L253,277L259,277L266,277L271,277L277,277L281,277L284,277L288,277L293,277L297,276L302,274L305,272L308,271L311,268L313,267L315,264L318,261L322,257L324,254L326,249L329,244L331,241L332,239L334,234L338,230L339,226L341,222L343,218L345,213L347,211L348,207L349,201L351,196L352,192L353,187L353,183L353,180L353,178L354,176L354,173L354,170L354,168L354,167L354,166L354,164L354,162L354,161L354,159L354,158L354,155L354,152L354,149L352,143L349,137L347,133L343,125L340,119 M241,59L340,119";

d3.select("#g-1").append("path").attr("d", points);


//simplify the path

function DouglasPeucker(){

}



/*
//http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer-Douglas-Peucker_algorithm


function DouglasPeucker(PointList[], epsilon)
    // Find the point with the maximum distance
    dmax = 0
    index = 0
    end = length(PointList)
    for i = 2 to ( end - 1) {
        d = shortestDistanceToSegment(PointList[i], Line(PointList[1], PointList[end])) 
        if ( d > dmax ) {
            index = i
            dmax = d
        }
    }
    // If max distance is greater than epsilon, recursively simplify
    if ( dmax > epsilon ) {
        // Recursive call
        recResults1[] = DouglasPeucker(PointList[1...index], epsilon)
        recResults2[] = DouglasPeucker(PointList[index...end], epsilon)

        // Build the result list
        ResultList[] = {recResults1[1...end-1] recResults2[1...end]}
    } else {
        ResultList[] = {PointList[1], PointList[end]}
    }
    // Return the result
    return ResultList[]
end
*/
```

Comment: Can you pose this in question form? I'm not 100% sure what you are asking

Comment: Have you seen [simplify.js](http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/)?

Comment: How do you a) - get the path data and churn it through a function - which I think takes the points and checks for the shortest distances - essentially want to recreate the path with fewer points - making the shape simpler more polygon like.

Comment: I've seen this simplify.js but only saw examples that relate to maps

Comment: http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/smoothing-simplifying-flattening/

Comment: Having no luck - http://jsfiddle.net/jEfsh/61/

Comment: Some how I need to loop through the path to get its x, y coordinates and then try and process this through the simplifier - http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/8163268

Comment: How do I adapt the prime example to use the simplifier - its not a geo location point.

Comment: here is the latest code - with some pseudo code - http://jsfiddle.net/jEfsh/62/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/3/

Comment: Great stuff man. How did you do that? What does the epsilon represent?  Are you able to add some comments to the code

Comment: M Oehm, if you can add the latest code with comments as an answer - I'll mark this as complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what your problem is exactly. Do you have problems to turn the SVG data string into a list of points? You can use this:

```
function path_from_svg(svg) {
    var pts = svg.split(/[ML]/);
    var path = [];

    console.log(pts.length);
    for (var i = 1; i < pts.length; i++) {
        path.push(pts[i].split(","));
    }

    return path;
}
```

It is a very simple approach: It splits the string on all move (`M`) and line (`L`) commands and treats them as lines. It then splits all substrings on the comma. The first "substring" is ignored, because it is the empty string before the first `M`. If there is a way to do this better in `d3` I haven't found it.

The reverse operation is easier:

```
function svg_to_path(path) {
    return "M" + path.join("L");
}
```

This is equivalent to `svg.line.interpolate("linear")`.

You can then implement the Douglas-Peucker algorithm on this path data recursively:

```
function path_simplify_r(path, first, last, eps) {
    if (first >= last - 1) return [path[first]];

    var px = path[first][0];
    var py = path[first][1];

    var dx = path[last][0] - px;
    var dy = path[last][1] - py;

    var nn = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    var nx = -dy / nn;
    var ny = dx / nn;

    var ii = first;
    var max = -1;

    for (var i = first + 1; i < last; i++) {
        var p = path[i];

        var qx = p[0] - px;
        var qy = p[1] - py;

        var d = Math.abs(qx * nx + qy * ny);
        if (d > max) {
            max = d;
            ii = i;
        }
    }

    if (max < eps) return [path[first]];

    var p1 = path_simplify_r(path, first, ii, eps);
    var p2 = path_simplify_r(path, ii, last, eps);

    return p1.concat(p2);        
}

function path_simplify(path, eps) {
    var p = path_simplify_r(path, 0, path.length - 1, eps);
    return p.concat([path[path.length - 1]]);
}
```

The distance to the line is not calculated in a separate function but directly with the formula for the distance of a point to a 2d line from the normal `{nx, ny}` on the line vector `{dx, dy}` between the first and last point. The normal is normalised, `nx*nx + ny*ny == 1`.

When creating the paths, only the first point is added, the last point `path[last]` is implied and must be added in `path_simplify`, which is a front end to the recursive function `path_simplify_r`. This approach was chosen so that concatenating the left and right subpaths does not create a duplicate point in the middle. (This could equally well and maybe cleaner be done by joining `p1` and `p2.slice(1)`.)

Here's everything put together in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/3/

Comment: Cheers man, trying to apply this to the following application - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423786/d3-js-lasso-drawing-polygon-shape-search-tool-on-a-google-map-getting-the-coo

Comment: Trying to add an edit shape to this - I've added a button - trying to place circles on the various polygon points - and then try and redraw them if dragged - http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/5/

Comment: Very cool to see the code in action. (I'm not a d3.js expert and I'm sure there must be a simple, more d3.js-ey solution to this. Anyway, good to see it works.)

Comment: This is the edit code - but I don't know how to adapt it to the example - http://jsfiddle.net/4xXQT/156/

Comment: This is the application in its entirety of what I am trying to achieve - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423786/d3-js-lasso-drawing-polygon-shape-search-tool-on-a-google-map-getting-the-coo/22559135#22559135

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good references in the comments to this question -- alas they are comments and not suggested answers which can be truly voted on.

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/

shows interactive use of this kind of thing which references Douglas-Peucker but also Visvalingam.

Comment: You guys have a lot of experience with the paths etc... how can I get it work with the googlemaps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22687168/2700673