# Google Heatmap - select points

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Looking to select a set of points when using Google heatmaps - see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap). The idea is to have some kind or region or circle based selection that returns the set of points that are inside this area with the user being able to define the area graphically.

The problem indeed is how this selection should work. Has anyone seen or done something similar ?

Comment: please define "how this selects should work"....can you please re-state what you are intending to do?

Comment: hope is better now

Comment: ok  selecting points is different than generating a heat map.  I believe you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423786/d3-js-lasso-drawing-polygon-shape-search-tool-on-a-google-map-getting-the-coo

Comment: that's it thanks :-)